# R: Webscraping JSON files?

Tags: html, r, json, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language.

I have a website (e.g. https://mywebsite.com) where the source code (i.e. ctrl+u) looks something like this:

```
[
{

"title1" : "abc 123",
"title2" : "bca 321",
"title3" : "cba 213",
"title4" : {"title5": "title6", "title7": [ -17662.3456, 987621.7654]}
},

...


{

"title1" : "aec 183",
"title2" : "bga 351",
"title3" : "cha 293",
"title4" : {"title5": "title6", "title7": [ -1621626123.23234, 652238322.122]}
}]
```

I would like to extract the information in "title7" for each "block of code" (e.g. if there are "n" blocks). This would look something like this:

```
# final result

  id      title7_1    title7_2
 1 -1.766235e+04    987621.8
......
  n -1.621626e+09 652238322.1
```

I was able to bring this website into R.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)

url <- " https://mywebsite.com"
page <- read_html(url)
```

This looks something like this:

```
>page

{html_document]
<html>

[1] <body><p>[\r\n{r\n "title1": "abc 123", \r\n  "title2" : "bca 321" , \r\n, .....
```

I tried to further inspect this:

```
>str(page)

List of 2
$node: <externalptr>
$doc: <externalptr>
- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2]  "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

But from here, I don't know what to do. I thought that maybe I could try to extract this information like this - But this produces an empty output::

```
library(dplyr)
page %>% html_nodes("title4")

{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I have feeling that I am not doing this correctly seeing as this website does not appear to be in typical HTML format and actually might be in JSON format. **Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?**

Thanks!

**Note:** It looks like the website was successfully loaded into R and the "page" object was successfully create. Perhaps some function like "grep/gsub" could be used to extract these numbers the "page" object? **Seeing that the information from the website has already been imported into R - **can something be done that takes advantage of this fact?****

Comment: It would help if we could see a specific website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. I set up a similar page on an internal website.

```r
library(rvest)
res <- read_html("https://...../quux.json") # not a real domain here
res
# {html_document}
# <html>
# [1] <body><p>[\n{\n"title1" : "abc 123",\n"title2" : "bca 321",\n"title3" : "cba 213 ...
```

We just need to get to the html text:

```r
quux <- jsonlite::parse_json(html_text(res), simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
str(quux)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ title1: chr  "abc 123" "aec 183"
#  $ title2: chr  "bca 321" "bga 351"
#  $ title3: chr  "cba 213" "cha 293"
#  $ title4:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ title5: chr  "title6" "title6"
#   ..$ title7:List of 2
#   .. ..$ : num  -17662 987622
#   .. ..$ : num  -1.62e+09 6.52e+08
```

From here, you can subset the list to get just the components you need, such as this matrix:

```r
do.call(rbind, quux$title4$title7)
#               [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] -1.766235e+04    987621.8
# [2,] -1.621626e+09 652238322.1
```

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you so much! Is "parse_json" from the "jsonlite" library - or is it from the "jsontools" library? thank you so much!

Comment: just a question: is there some other alternative for the "parse_json" function? perhaps something from base R, jsonlite or rjson that can be used instead? Thank you so much!

Comment: Base R has no JSON parsing functionality, and trying to do it yourself will beat rather large endeavor. I don't understand, though: I used `jsonlite::parse_json` and you're looking for an alternative in base, `rjson`, or ... `jsonlite`?

Answer (score 1):

The page might require JavaScript if you cannot access it with rvest, provided that you have the css/XPath correct. You can go to Chrome -> Inspect -> Network -> XHR -> and search for the json or api that stores your data.